# How to run multiple roscore/master in a single machine?

Tags: ros, roscore, parallel, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

A superset question is [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11395/can-multiple-instances-of-gazebo-andor-roscore-run-in-parallel/), where it is said that we have to change the ROS_MASTER_URI to run the 2nd master.

I have tried running the 1st master with ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 (default), then in another terminal did the following:

```
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://torPC2:11315/
$ echo $ROS_MASTER_URI
http://torPC2:11315/
$ roscore
...
roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching.
The ROS_MASTER_URI is http://torPC2:11311/
```

So, how to make roscore know that the ROS_MASTER_URI now in the 2nd terminal is http://torPC2:11315/ ?
or How to run multiple roscore/master in a single machine?

My use case requires completely independent roscores/masters and even they do not need to communicate each others. Simply, it is like having multiple isolated machines with one running roscore/master in each of them.

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57539/how-to-run-multiple-roscore/master-in-a-single-machine?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the -p port option to bring up another one on a different port.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4